# Difference betweet style.visibility and style.display

Tags: javascript, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

I am looking at examples to hide/show `div` tags using JavaScript. 
In some examples, they use `visibility` and in some `display`.

e.g.

```
document.getElementById("divhotel").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

vs

```
document.getElementById("divhotel").style.display = "none";
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 15):

When you set [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) to `hidden`, the element is not shown but still takes up the same space on the page.

When you get [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) to `none`, the element is neither shown nor does it take up any space on the page.

More often than not I find myself using `display`, but it depends on what your scenario demands.

Answer (score 2):

`visibility` is how the element is rendered, the block where it exists is still laid out regardless of the value. Items might be pushed around because of that. `display` is how it is rendered to the page: `block` is `div` type elements, with a full box models; `none` element isn't rendered to the page at all; `inline` is an inline element such as a `span` or anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, beloved [Google](http://p2p.wrox.com/javascript-how/3884-difference-between-style-visibility-style-disp.html).

"style.visiblity makes the element visible or hidden, it is still rendered and takes up space on the page even if you can't see it. If you set style.display to "none" the markup is not processed and does not take up space on the page."

Comment: You guys are too fast.  +1 each.