# Expand div upon clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a div that has the full height of it's content set to 500px. First 200px of the 500px is, lets say, a preview. So I set it's height to 200px and `overflow: hidden`. I then added this script:

```
<div class="stretcher">
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $('.stretcher').toggle(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'height': '500px'}, 300);
        }, 
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'height': '200px'}, 300);
        }
    );
</script>
```

That works but the problem is that I need the contents of the div to be clickable. However, with this script wherever I click it either expands the div or returns it back to the original 200px.

Any idea how I could do it? Maybe adding icons of arrow up and down or something.

Comment: Please share your HTML. Is stretcher 500px height initially? Or is it a container for "preview" element?

Comment: Instead of changing the height, why don't you show/hide content? Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326925/difference-betweet-style-visibility-and-style-display

Comment: You will get more information over here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Comment: @SwapneelKondgule http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 4):

The `toggle()` function used that way is deprecated and removed in newer versions of jQuery, use a flag instead :

```
$('.stretcher').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        var h = $(this).height() > 220;
        $(this).animate({'height': ( h ? 200 : 500 ) }, 300);
    }
});
```

Checking if the `target` equals `this` stops any problems when clicking other elements inside `.strecher`

Comment: (+1) This is the best way to do it. The `===` ensures that it is an exact match. In this situation this means that if there is another clickable element within the div it will respect that element and not `.toggle`

Comment: this is really good but as ive seen i need to click on edges of div for this to work... anyways i really appriciate help but i used Archers code.. works like a charm since i created half of those upper 200px to be clickable in order to expand or contract. thnx once more

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<div class="stretcher">
    <div class="clickable"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $('.clickable').toggle(
        function()
        {
            $(this).parent().animate({'height': '500px'}, 300);
        }, 
        function()
        {
            $(this).parent().animate({'height': '200px'}, 300);
        }
    );
</script>
```

You have an area called `clickable` and when you click that it animates the parent container div, but it won't do it when you click the div itself.

Comment: thnx m8 ... tihs works for me like a charm.. this clickable div i positioned and puted where i need it and eveyrthing works gr8..thnx

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your code in a function that has an exact match. As @adeneo points out. An example below using your existing code in this manner.

```
$('.stretcher').on('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target === this) {
        $('.stretcher').toggle(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'height': '500px'}, 300);
        }, 
        function(){
            $(this).animate({'height': '200px'}, 300);
        }
    );
    }
});
```